# interpreting dual norm of quadratic norm with change of basis

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

I'm trying to compute
$$
\|z\|_* := \sup_{\|x\|_A\leq1} |z^T x|
$$
for $\|x\|_A^2 := x^T A x$ with $A \succ 0$, symmetric. I see that we're looking at $z^T \in \mathbb{R}^n$ as a linear functional, so this is really the operator norm with $|\cdot|$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\|\cdot\|_A$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I make a change of coordinates $y = A^{1/2}x$ and substitute to get
$$
\|z\|_* := \sup_{\|y\|_2\leq1} |z^T A^{-1/2}y|.
$$
Based on @max_zorn's comment, I use symmetry of $A$ so that 
$$
\|z\|_* = \sup_{y^T y=1}|A^{-1/2}z^T y| = \sup_{\|y\|_2=1}|A^{-1/2}z^T y| \leq \|A^{-1/2}z\|_2 \|y\|_2
$$
with equality at $y = A^{-1/2}z / \|A^{-1/2}z\|_2$ so $\|z\|_* = \|A^{-1/2}z\|_2$.

What is the functional analysis explanation for why the dual norm should be computable as the euclidean norm of the transformed vector $A^{-1/2}z$? How can I think about duality more intuitively in this case?

Comment: $\langle z,A^{-1/2}y\rangle = \langle A^{-1/2}z,y\rangle$

Comment: So you have $\|z\|_*=\sup_{y^Ty=1} |A^{-1/2}z^T y| $. Then what?

Comment: You are done. This computes the Euclidean norm of $A^{-1/2}{z}$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not seeing how. Can you clarify?

Comment: $\max_{\|y\|\leq 1} \langle w,y\rangle = \|w\|$. To see this, Observe that Cauchy-Schwarz gives LHS $\leq$ RHS. To get equality, consider $y=w/\|w\|$.

Comment: Hoping if anyone would be so kind to explain how $y$ was determined for that equality at the end of the proof.

Answer (score 1):

When $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, $A^{-1/2}$ is also symmetric and positive definite. Thus
$$\|A^{-1/2} z\|_2 = \|z\|_{A^{-1}}.$$
Thus,
$\|\cdot\|_A$ and $\|\cdot\|_{A^{-1}}$
are dual to each other.
I don't have an intuitive reason for why this is true,
but it at least seems quite natural.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you drop a power exponent of 1/2 in the term $||x||_A = (x^TAx)^{1/2}$

Comment: I'm not sure this actually answers the question

Comment: Well, I didn't put it clearly, I mean that the question do help me a lot, and my point is in fact the latter. Feel sorry to reedit my answer.